# How to use oc command to scale up a Deployment instead of DeploymentConfig

Tags: openshift

Do anyone know the oc command which do the same job when I am clicking the **"Up" arrow** in deployment?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just try and find the answer:

```
oc scale deployments/cakephp-dw-git --replicas=1
```